# Index of / with blank page output on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, server

I uploaded my PHP(codeigniter) project on server. But when I run it I get below window

```
Index of /

Name    Last modified   Size    Description
Apache Server at 'ip address here' Port 80
```

project folder is in /var/www/

DocumentRoot is set in projectName.conf directory as /var/www/projectName

Comment: Have you got an `.htaccess` in your public folder?

Comment: .htaccess in project folder

Comment: codeigniter has a public folder, yes? Put the .htaccess in there, make sure the vhost points there

Comment: Yes I already have htaccess in codeigniter folder

Comment: You have to check what error code you are getting 404 or 500 ? Also make sure your default controller name starts with Capital and .htaccess is not blocking.

Comment: @delboy1978uk  How I can check vhost ?

Comment: @BSB no any error code.

Comment: If Apache, it should be in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/something.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your site `.conf` points to the public folder and not the site root.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site.co.uk/public

        <Directory "/var/www/site.co.uk/">
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                AllowOverride FileInfo All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: My DocumentRoot is  /var/www/projectName

Comment: This is from one of my sites. Note the `Directory` part points to the site root, yet `DocumentRoot` points to `public`. This tells Apache that all the files are in the Directory `/var/www/site.co.uk/`, but a call to `www.site.co.uk` would take you to the DocumentRoot of `/var/www/site.co.uk/public`

Comment: I am accessing using IP. Does it need any change in conf, If I access using ServerName then error is **server DNS address could not be found**

Comment: in `/etc/hosts`, you can add `127.0.0.1 site.co.uk` and it should resolve. If your server isn't on your laptop, change the IP address!

Comment: Do you meanas  ServerName ip projectName in conf file ? I do not have hosts file in etc. there are folders like. sites-enabled, sites-available

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help! Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure about 3 points for this issue

1. Need `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/projectName/.htaccess` which is provided by Codeigniter
2. Must have rewrite module enabled.
   If you are using Ubuntu OS and apache2 then execute `sudo a2enmod rewrite` in your terminal to enable this.
3. Must allow override URL by `.htaccess` rule in `apache.conf` for `/var/www` folder.
   If you are using Ubuntu OS and apache2 then edit file `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` and change `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride All` in block/section of `<directory /var/www>` and then restart apache by `sudo service apache2 restart` command.

Comment: Tried. still same issue